# Is fflush(stdout) interfering with sprintf() in this snippet?

Tags: c, unix, stdio

The purpose of this Unix program is to kill process 2, and test my understanding of fork, exec and kill.
Intended chronology:

0s: process 1 prints 2 things and kills process 2

1s: nothing because process 2 is gone

2s: process 3 prints

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
        int id = fork();
        if (id==0)
        {
                id = fork();
                if (id==0)
                {
                        sleep (2);
                        printf ("this is process 3 ");
                }
                else
                {
                        sleep (1);
                        printf ("this is process 2 ");
                }
        }
        else
        {
                printf ("this is process 1 ");
                char s[20];
                sprintf (s,"%d",id);
                printf ("kill %s",s);
                fflush (stdout);
                execlp ("kill","kill",s);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
[terminal handle]$ ./a.out
this is process 1 kill 2437kill: cannot find process "H="
[terminal handle]$ this is process 3
```

I think what's probably going on is fflush(stdout) is interfering with sprintf, but I don't see why it would deal with something other than stdout.
I tried commenting out fflush and got:

```
[terminal handle]$ ./a.out
[terminal handle]$ this is process 3
```

So probably the killing of process 2 is killing the printf of process 1 before the buffer is flushed? I originally added fflush to fix this.
If I add newlines in the printf's to flush it that way and comment out fflush, it behaves almost as expected:

```
[terminal handle]$ ./a.out
this is process 1
kill 2505
[terminal handle]$ this is process 3

[terminal handle]$
```

I don't understand:

what is going on with fflush in the first output,

why the terminal handle behaves the way it does.

Is there a way to do this without newlines and without the problem in the first example?

EDIT: I tried them all 4 or 5 times, and the output stays the same except for the pid. This includes the "H=" bit.
EDIT2: fixed, thanks.

Comment: The last argument to `execlp` needs to be `(char *) NULL`. You need to add that after the last argument.

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp. What @cheatah said. Also, I'm not sure `id` is what you think it is at that point.